# fwrite in data.table changed my string column to integer, how to fix?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm writing a data table to csv using `fwrite`. The function changes the class of one column from character to integer and deleted the starting zeros, which I do not want. So my var2 here is character, and I would like to preserve that through fwrite then fread a subset.

However, what I got was the following:

```r
head(DT)
var1 var2
 1  "0012"
 2  "0032"
 3  "0043" 

DT1 <- DT[var1!=2,]

fwrite(DT1,"DT1.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Then:

```r
DT1 <- fread("DT1.csv")
head(DT1)
var1 var2
 1    12
 3    43
```

Is there any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `fread` rather than `fwrite`.  So just specify that `var2` is a `character` class.  The default in `fread` is sensing that `var2` is a `numeric` column so just add the following in your call to `fread`:

```
DT1<-fread("DT1.csv", colClasses = list(character=c("var2")))
```

Let me know if this works for you and good luck!

Comment: When I run `fwrite` locally it retains my character column. When run from posit connect, it changes the character column into a date and mutilates the year from 4 to 2 digit.